# Can you help identify this fish i caught?

Tags: fishing, animal-identification

I think it may be a salmon but the green colour is throwing me off.

[image][image]

Comment: Do you have any more information? Where did you catch it?

Comment: @ChrisMendez in a river in Southern Ontario a few km from lake Ontario

Answer (score 7):

Looks kind of like a **walleye** to me.

I didn't think there was anything else worth catching in Ontario, in NW Ontario at least this is what everyone goes fishing for, they're one of the tastier fishes.

[image]

They're fighters too, you always expect them to big bigger than they are when you reel them in.

Comment: This is one of the best eating freshwater fish in North America.

Comment: Walleyes and crappies are the best.

Comment: definitely a walleye, this is the correct answer